# Creating a numbered list without periods in Powerpoint

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2016

In Microsoft Powerpoint 2016, how do I create a numbered list without any periods that continues across slides?

For example:

Slide 1:
1
2

Slide2:
3
4

Comment: It appears you cannot remove the period. You can in Word but not PowerPoint. I tried normal and Admin mode to change this.

Comment: I agree there isn't a high level of customization on numeric bullets in Powerpoint. I think it cannot be done.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit bizarre, and it may only apply to some versions of PPT (I've since tested using 365, 2019 and 2010 under Windows; works in all of them), but assuming you've added a new slide (Title and Content) and clicked into the Content placeholder:

Type 1 then TAB then the text for your first numbered point. If the line wraps, it'll look wrong but keep typing.

When you press ENTER at the end of the first line, it'll fix the indents and add a new line with 2 in place already.

It won't automatically continue numbering on the next slide, but if you start with, e.g. 5 then TAB, it'll keep up the numbering from there.

Editing? Good luck with that. Once it's sort of halfway decided that the numbers are numbers/bullets, it won't let you change them.

Comment: This also works for PowerPoint for Office Professional & Plus 2016.